# Alternative definition of pairing function such that the numbers $\pi(k_1,k_2)$ comprise a field analogous to $\mathbb C$

Tags: number-theory, number-systems

Consider the pairing function $\pi:\mathbb{N\times N\to N}$
as given by [wikipedia/Pairing_function](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairing_function), and let's just write
$(k_1,k_2)\in\mathbb{N}\ $ for $\pi(k_1,k_2)$. Then the canonical
definition, as given by wikipedia, doesn't sensibly interpret
the sum $n=(i,j)+(k,l)$.   That is, if we use the inverse
construction to determine the "components" $(r,s)=n$ of the sum,
then $i+k\neq r$,   $j+l\neq s$, and there's no kind of
sensible/intuitive algebraic relation whatsoever that I can see.

So is there any alternative definition of $\pi:\mathbb{N\times N\to N}$
such that, at least with respect to addition, *"the sum of components equals the components of the sum"*, or some sensible algebraic relation between them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not.

Note that $\pi$ being enumeration implies $(a, b) = (c, d)$ iff $a = c$ and $b = d$.

Let $x = (1, 2)$ and $y = (2, 1)$.

You require that $(na, nb) = n\cdot (a, b) = (a, b) \cdot n$, because $$n \cdot (a, b) =\\ (a, b) + (a, b) + \ldots + (a, b) = (a + a, b + b) + \ldots + (a, b) = (a + \ldots + a, b + \ldots + b) =\\(na, nb)$$

But then $(1 \cdot y, 2 \cdot y) = (1, 2) \cdot (2, 1) = (2 \cdot x, 1 \cdot x)$, then $y = 2x$ and $x = 2y$, which is impossible unless $x = y = 0$, but even then $\pi$ is not an enumeration.

More generally, you ask if $\mathbb N$ and $\mathbb N \times \mathbb N$ are isomorphic as semigroups. But semigroup rank (minimal number of elements of our semigroup such that minimal subsemigroup containing them is the semigroup itself) is preserved under isomorphism, while rank of $\mathbb N$ is $1$ and rank of $\mathbb N \times \mathbb N$ is $2$.

Comment: Thanks, @mihaild. But  I don't think I specifically asked about isomorphism; bijection is fine. And I think the "squiggly line" diagram on the cited wikipedia page informally demonstrates that. And also, although the subject line says **field**, the question elaborates _"at least with respect to addition"_. I'm just looking for as many field-like properties as possible. I kind of need something like the illustrated addition example for my purposes, and although scalar multiplication would certainly be nice, it's not strictly necessary for me.

Comment: You ask about bijection that preserves addition, it is exactly isomorphism as semigroups. Added note about scalar multiplication.

Comment: Thanks, again. Didn't realize that.